# Zooming and Drawing on Canvas with Touch events

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, zooming, inkmanager

I have a Windows Store App that looks like a Paint App where I can draw using Touch events (InkManager class with Pointer events) and I can zoom (Zoom the Canvas contained into a ScrollViewer after Clicking the ZoomButton to enable Zooming on it).

The problem is that it works fine when I test it on my PC with Mouse Events but when I test it on My Tablet, Ink doesn't show and I can't write. It moves the Canvas to left and right only, and Zooms when Zoom is enabled.

How can I differentiate touch events between Zoom and Ink?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Manipulation event instead of Touch event